# Reports Codeigniter so hard code

Tags: php, codeigniter, report

Right now, I am using CI 3.0 . And for create report like invoice, monthly report sales, I using dompdf which is so spending time to debug coz dompdf not really support JS.

I was wondering a tools like crystal report , drag and drop report. I am not sure that PHP have like that.

I found [php-reports](http://jdorn.github.io/php-reports/), it looks interesting. But I dont know how to integrate it.

Perhaps, someone out there have solution to this PHP Reports, or maybe if you are share how to simplified creating a report in CI.

Thank You

Comment: Why down vote to close ?

Comment: a lot of previous questions on using code igniter for reports and pdf output eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377522/page-number-for-dynamically-generated-pages-in-mpdf

Answer (score 1):

maybe look at; http://www.hkvstore.com/phpreportmaker/

this questions lightly talks about using it; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910080/codeigniter-with-php-report-maker)

CI is great in that you are allowed to break the rules if you want. if its painful working inside the M-V-C approach then bend some rules or look at another method; like writing a library, or have your model generate more than just the dataset and include html ready for your CSS that your view just has to output (rather than parse).